# Docker build (MacOS vs Ubuntu)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-build

On a Mac OSX, it's possible to do this to build the docker image from a `Dockerfile`:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile .
```

And on a Debian/Ubuntu, the above doesn't work, it just hangs there.

```
docker build - < Dockerfile
```

But Mac OSX can take both syntax. **Why is that so?**

---

Is it because of the different Docker versions or different Dockers on different OS?

Docker on Mac:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Tue Mar 28 00:40:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.04.0-ce
 API version:  1.28 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   4845c56
 Built:        Wed Apr  5 18:45:47 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Docker on Ubuntu:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:23:31 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:19:04 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

If it's the different Docker version, does it mean that the `docker build -f Dockerfile .` is deprecated since the Mac version is older than the Ubuntu one?

Comment: Different docker versions?

Comment: Can you try to build again, but use `docker --debug build -f Dockerfile .` on the client, and run the daemon in debug mode as well? The hanging behavior certainly is not expected, so I would recommend grabbing that information and posting it so that you can get help with solving underlying problem.

Answer (score 2):

As I see in my version, it is working. I'll let this answer stay here so that we know that

`docker build -f Dockerfile .`

works on docker version 3 on mac, docker version 5 on ubuntu, and hangs on docker version 6 on ubuntu.

**Original Answer:**
My system runs on ubuntu and I tested both the methods to build and both worked the same way. First one being

`docker build -f Dockerfile .`

and second being

`docker build - < Dockerfile`

Maybe taking a look at my docker version would help:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```